# phonegap google map, Uncaught ReferenceError: plugin is not defined

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I am using phonegap plugin cordova-plugin-googlemaps
https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

but map is not loading and I am getting following error in console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: plugin is not defined
at Channel.<anonymous> (my-app.js:55)
at Channel.fire (cordova.js:797)
at cordova.js:229
```

here is JS code where I got error

```
var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);
```

can anybody help me. Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this issue are available on official **GIT Repo** of plugin.

Take a look here: [plugin is not defined](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/140)